# Electron-webpack: css and html loaders arent' working

Tags: webpack, electron, webpack-loader

I have an electron app. I want to bundle it with webpack but I just can't seem to be able to parse the css and html files.
I've added the `html-loader` and `css-loader` and this is my config file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                loaders: ["url-loader?limit=5000&name=img/img-[hash:6].[ext]"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loaders: ["html-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I keep getting this message:

```
WARNING in ./src/styles.css
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:5)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

I get the same error for HTML files:

```
WARNING in ./src/page1.html
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

The place in which I call the HTML file is this:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/src/page1.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        }));
```

The strangest thing is - the only place in which I call the `css` file is inside the `html` file (using the `link` tag).

Any idea as to what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue. It seems that if I use the `rules` property instead of the `loaders` it works.  So my webpack config looks like this:

```
{
 entry: "./src/app.js",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ["url-loader?limit=5000&name=img/img-[hash:6].[ext]"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ["raw-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```